# How do I upload verification photos to Apple's Maps Connect?

Tags: apple-id, maps

I'm trying to submit my place of business to Apple's [Maps Connect](https://mapsconnect.apple.com) so that it shows up in Apple Maps, but my submission was rejected (unable to verify) until I upload verification photos. Here's exactly what it says:

> **Upload Verification Photos**
>
> Please return to your business profile at Maps Connect and upload verification photos or videos. These must show your locations building and external sign, or building directory matching your business name. This will help us verify that your business is physically located at the address on your profile.

However, I can't find any place in Maps Connect that allows me to upload verification photos or videos. Is this a hidden feature? Is there some trick that allows me to upload verification photos? Has anyone else managed to do this?

Comment: Did you select the location that has the alert / icon? Also, what OS and browser are you logging in to the web site? You might need to enable location to that browser per the help / faq on the site

Comment: @bmike Yes I selected the location with the alert, and yes I have location services enabled. Firefox 67 on macOS 10.14 Mojave. I also tried with Safari 12.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like email is the only way to send verification photos right now. This is the email response I received after reaching out to Support for Maps Connect.

> Regarding your inquiry, please reply to this message directly with a photo from outside your business.